# ingresar valores en el input y que me vaya mostrando los resultados de la tabla de multiplicar

Tags: javascript, html

En este caso lo que estoy queriendo lograr es ingresar el valor en el input y ver el resultado eso se ejecuta y se muestra correctamente el problema es que al darle click me mustra solo el resultado de la operacion pero no los titulos ej.:
Curso de Javascript
Ejercicio de tabla de multiplicar
y la tabla

```js
function multiplicar() {
  let cabeza = document.getElementById("cabecera").innerHTML;
  let input = document.getElementById("numero").value;
  let contador = 2;

  document.write(cabeza + "</br>");

  while (contador <= 10) {
    document.write(input + " x " + contador + " = " + contador * input + "</br>");
    contador++;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cabecera">
    <h1>Curso de Javascript</h1>
    <h3>Ejercicio de tabla de multiplicar</h3>
    <form>
      <input type="number" id="numero" />
      <button  onclick="multiplicar()">Consultar</button>
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
    </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usar `document.write` luego de que el documento fue cargado completamente, borra todo el contenido html. El snippet está mal como tal, 2 de las etiquetas del html no cierran una con otra. Si nos indicas el resultado como dicen arriba, se puede ayudar.

Comment: A que te refieres que no sale? yo lo ejecuto y luego de presionar el botón consultar, si puedo ver los textos de "Curso de Javascript" y de "Ejercicio de tabla de multiplicar"

Comment: buenas cuando vuelvo a ingresar otro valor y consultar solo me sale la tabla del 1 al 10 con los resultado de cada uno pero no me vuleve a a mostrar "Curso de Javascript" y de "Ejercicio de tabla de multiplicar" y el input para volver a ingresar de vuelta otro valores

Comment: @MarceloJoseSosaSosa me avisas si mi respuesta es lo que necesitabas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda Cris223511.dev es justo lo que necesitaba ni mas ni menos gracias a tu respuesta me ayudaste a comprender mejor muchas cosas genio Total !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar `innerHTML` en vez de `document.write()`, tendrías que crear un nuevo `div` debajo para mostrar los resultados, y cuando digitas otro número, el contenido del nuevo `div` se va a sobrescribir con los nuevos resultados. También me percaté que al volver a digitar y enviar el formulario (ya que es un `form`), ocurre el evento del **submit**, redirigiéndote a una página en blanco y así estarías **perdiendo** todos los datos, puedes evitar esto usando `preventDefault()`. Ejemplo:

```js
function multiplicar(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // evito el evento por defecto del submit
  let input = document.getElementById("numero").value; // obtengo al número.
  let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado"); // obtengo al div "resultado".
  let contador = 2;

  resultado.innerHTML = ""; // vacío el contenido del div "resultado".

  resultado.innerHTML += "Tabla de multiplicar del " + input + ":</br></br>"

  while (contador <= 10) {
    let fila = input + " x " + contador + " = " + contador * input + "</br>";
    resultado.innerHTML += fila; // y cada fila (que será repetida por el while) lo muestro en el div "resultado".
    contador++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cabecera">
  <h1>Curso de Javascript</h1>
  <h3>Ejercicio de tabla de multiplicar</h3>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="numero" />
    <button onclick="multiplicar(event)">Consultar</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="resultado"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```